# Delete ListView item based on bindingcontext

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a listview that is being populated from an SQLite DB. The XML looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="CalculationListview" ItemsSource="{Binding Calculation}" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Qty}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Note}"></Label>
                    <Button Text="Delete" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have created a button as you can see, from which I want to delete the item from the database if it's clicked.

I have already made a method for deleting from the database, that takes in a given object.

```
public Task<int> DeleteCalculationAsync(Calculation calculation)
{
    return database.DeleteAsync(calculation);
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fetch the object from my bindingcontext so that I can delete the item. I obviously have the clicked eventhandler in place already:

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    App.Database.DeleteCalculationAsync(SOMETHING HERE);
}
```

Comment: this looks like you should do something like `var selectedItem =Calculation.Single(x=>x.Id == calculation.id);` that will give you the correct value from your binding

Comment: Im not sure i can do Calculation.single() in that context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Context Actions

I recommend moving the delete functionality to [Context Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin).

The Context Actions will appear on iOS when the user swipes right-to-left on the ViewCell and on Android when the user long-presses the ViewCell.

### Example Screenshot

This screenshot is from the Xamarin.Forms docs and does not reflect the code below.

[image]

### Code

```xml
<ListView x:Name="CalculationListview" ItemsSource="{Binding Calculation}" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" Clicked="Handle_Delete"/>
                 </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Qty}"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Note}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```cs
async void Handle_Delete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var viewCellSelected = sender as MenuItem;
    var calculationToDelete = viewCellSelected?.BindingContext as Calculation;

    await App.Database.DeleteCalculationAsync(calculationToDelete);
}
```